# how can my code could be written more succinctly?

Tags: python, function, loops

Question: how can my code could be written more succinctly?

Background:

Working on Automate the boring stuff challenges in Python. The program below is meant to:

1. get the user to enter an integer
2. check that what was entered was an integer (with try and except)
3. perform the collatz() function on that sequence

CODE:

```
def accept_int():
        while True: 
                try:
                        i = int(input()) 
                        break 
                except ValueError:
                        print('Please enter an integer value: ')
                        continue  
        return i 

def collatz(i):
        while num > 1:
                if i % 2 == 1:
                    return 3* i + 1
        else:
            return i // 2

print('Hello, please enter an integer: ')
num = accept_int()

while num > 1:
    num = collatz(num)
    print(num)
```